# Where to add code in wordpress js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am having trouble with where to add some js/jquery. code. I have a js file in my wordpress template and want to add a simple piece of code to show/hide a div, although it breaks the exisiting js/jquery. Where do I add it in the file, so it will not break it and/or what is the way to structure this file?

Exisiting Wordpress JS file...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {


//VIDEO

    var iframe = $('.videoPlayer')[0],
        player = $f(iframe),
        status = $('.status');

// When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
        status.text('ready');

        player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
        player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
        player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
    });

  // Call the API when a button is pressed
    $('.playPause').bind('click', function() {
        player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
       console.log('clicked'); // triggers
       player.api('paused', function(paused) {
       console.log('inside paused'); // doesn't trigger
            if (paused) {
              player.api('play');
            }
            else {
              player.api('pause');
            }
       });


    });    


    var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;

    // IFRAME RESIZE

    function videoWrapper() {
        var winW = $(window).width(); 
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winR = winH / winW;
        var video = $("#videoContainer iframe");
        // console.log( winW, winH, winR );

        // ratio of original video
        var vidR = video.attr("height") / video.attr("width");
        // ratio of iframe
        var ifrR = video.height() / video.width();
        // ifrR nedds to be 0.65

        //var diff = winW / (winH / vidR);
        if ( winR > vidR ) {
            // diff between current video height and winH
            var diff = winH / (winW * vidR);

            var newW = winW * diff;
            var newH = winW * diff * 0.65;

            video.css({
                "width": newW,
                "margin-left": 0 - (newW - winW) / 2,
                "margin-top": 0 - (newH - winH) / 2,
                "height": newH
            });
        } else {            
            video.css({
                "width": winW,
                "margin-left": "",
                "margin-top": 0 - ( (winW * 0.65) - winH ) / 2,
                "height": winW * 0.65
            });         
        }
    }

    // VIDEO SELECT

    if ( iOS ) {
        $("#kvVideo").remove();
        $("#kvVideoMobile").show();
    }

    // VIDEO MUTE

    if ( iOS ) {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("kvVideoMobile");
    } else {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("kvVideo");
    }

    var player = $f(iframe);

    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
        // player.api('setVolume', 0);

        // $("#videoContainer").on('click', function() {
        //     // Play the video
        //     player.api('play');
        //     alert("play");
        // });
    });

    function muteVideo () {
        player.api('setVolume', 0);
        mute = true; 
        $("#mute_button").hide();
        $("#volume_button").show();
        // console.log("mute"); 
    }

    function unmuteVideo () {
        player.api('setVolume', 1);
        mute = false;  
        $("#mute_button").show();
        $("#volume_button").hide(); 
        // console.log("unmute");         
    }

    var mute = false;
    $('#button').on("click", function(){
        // console.log("button click");
        if ( !mute ) {
            muteVideo();
        } else {
            unmuteVideo();
        }
    });



    // EVENTS

    $(window).on("load", function(){
        videoWrapper();
    }).on("resize", function(){
        videoWrapper();
        sectionCalc();
    });



});
```

The second part of code I want to add into the js file, so it will work with the code already there...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".colophon").hide();
    $(".newsletter").hide();

    $("#colophon").click(function(){
        $(".newsletter").hide();
        $(".colophon").fadeToggle('slow');      
    });

    $("#newsletter").click(function(){
        $(".colophon").hide();
        $(".newsletter").fadeToggle('slow');      
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: By "break", what do you mean exactly? What does your browser console say? How is the JS being loaded? Are you doing it by putting it in a `.js` file and then loading it via `wp_enqueue_script()`, or putting it directly in a theme file? Also, WP loads jQuery in non-conflict mode, so you will have to use `jQuery` instead of the `$` alias.

Comment: Thanks @Terry. I have the code in a .js file and it is loaded in my footer using...
 `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/js/script.js"></script>`. 
By break, I just mean when I add that second part of code into the same .js file they seem to cancel each other out and stop working. I just don't know how to add the two into one file What is the way to write/order this? thanks!

Comment: You haven't answered all my questions: (1) you know that **WP is using jQuery in compatible mode**. Replace `$(document).ready(function(){` with `jQuery(function($){`. And (2) what does your browser console log say? **What error messages are you seeing?**

Comment: Thanks Terry. My apologies. So I will put `jQuery(function($){` at the beginning of my exisiting js file. Does that replace `jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {`?
I am not getting any error message in console, it just doesn't work when it should. I had tested in js fiddle and there it worked fine. What would be the correct way to include the show/hide function in the .js file? thank you

Comment: `$(function(){...});` and `$(document).ready(function(){...});` are functionally identical, so is `jQuery(function(){...});` and `jQuery(document).ready(function(){...});`. The best way to incorporate third party scripts is to use `wp_enqueue_script()` in `functions.php` as mentioned before, instead of directly editing theme layout files.

Comment: Thanks Terry. Let me rephrase. I am making a wordpress theme that includes a js file that has different functions in it. Currently this is loaded in the footer. How do I structure that one js file so that the with multiple functions? For example, I have a section already that deals with video things and I want to add a simple show/hide div function using the code in the second block? Do I need to remove the `$(document).ready(function(){` before `$(".colophon").hide();` etc. is that causing a problem?

Comment: It is causing the problem because `$` is not recognised when jQuery is used in compatible mode. Replace it using the suggestions I have mentioned in my comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would create you own file and then enqueue it using WordPress's [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) in your functions.php file

Comment: Thanks @Tony Hensler. I have added the wp_enqueue_script() now to the functions file. How would you suggest I add the second part of the code into the .js file with the exisiting js content? thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't I would create my own js file.

Comment: do you mean have two js files? I already have my own js file. I just cannot add the second function into the exisiting js file that already includes other functions.

Comment: On a quick note are you sure your ha is working anyway as WordPress uses jQuery not $ in front of jQuery calls.